# How should I call external wcf web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, service-reference

there is external web service added to project with Service Reference. Is it necessary to do some extra manipulation with that, or methods and properties provided by web service is enough?
Here is how it's look like:

```
//Classes from web service
HHserviceClient h = new HHserviceClient();
HHPostPropertyRequest r = new HHPostPropertyRequest
  {
    //Web service properties
    Amenities = c.Amenities,
    ....
    MobileNo = c.MobileNo
  };
  //Method from web service
 h.PostProperty(r);
```

The problem with that is NullReference exception occurs when HHserviceClient calling, that's why I'm confused - should I call any .Net classes like HttpClient to do some extra job. I never did before any kind of job with external wcf web services and so I'm completely new to this and asking advise.

**UPDATE.**

```
      var rq = new HHPostPropertyRequest
                    {
                        Amenities = c.Amenities,
                        Area = c.Area,
                        BathRooms = c.BathRooms,
                        Bedrooms = c.Bedrooms,
                        City = c.City,
                        Company = c.Company,
                        Contact = c.Contact,
                        Country = c.Country,
                        CustomerID = 1000,
                        Description = c.Description,
                        Email = c.Email,
                        LandLineNo = c.LandLineNo,
                        Lattitude = c.Lattitude,
                        Location = c.Location,
                        Longitude = c.Longitude,
                        MobileNo = c.MobileNo
                    };
                BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://198.38.94.85/hhsvc/hhservice.svc/postproperty"); 
                ChannelFactory<IHHservice> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IHHservice>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
                IHHservice HHservice = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                var result = HHservice.PostProperty(rq);
                ((IClientChannel)HHservice).Close();
                myChannelFactory.Close();
```

Comment: Do you have any issues ?  Normally you already have everything if you add service ref via Visual Studio

Comment: That's why I'm confused. There is null reference exception throw when HHserviceClient called.

Comment: Can you show exception stack trace? Does your Property object has setters \ getters for all properties?

Comment: You can debug the constructor for client and check what is null.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebCrawler.dll System.NullReferenceException occurred
  _HResult=-2147467261
  _message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  HResult=-2147467261
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WebCrawler
  StackTrace:
       at WebCrawler.Repositories.ImportDataRepository.<ImportData>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\Users\andrey.shedko\Dropbox\WebCrawler\WebCrawler\Repositories\ImportDataRepository.cs:line 81
  InnerException:

Comment: Now it's clear "Could not find endpoint element with name 'PostProperty' and contract 'ServiceRefernce_HomeHunt.IHHservice' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element."

Comment: Do you have configuration in your App/Web Config with Endpoint ?

Comment: No, as I know I should be added when service reference added, but it's not.

Comment: Try to add manually ?  do you need example?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="myServiceSoapBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://....../service"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myServiceSoapBinding"
                contract="IMService" name="IMService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: Customer did not provide any documentation for his web service, so I don't know such things like contract etc. Can it be discovered somehow?

Comment: If you added WebService Ref, you already have folder ServiceReference.
File Reference.cs contains name of Interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try approach with Channel factory? It doesn't use generated configuration etc.

```
            var r = new Object()
            //define binding 
            //assume your binding using basicHttp, change it if you are using something else
            BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();           

            //define endpoint url              
            EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:11234/HHservice.svc"); //change to real endpoint 

            //Use channle factory instead of generated one
            ChannelFactory<IHHservice> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IHHservice>(myBinding, myEndpoint); //Change to you WCF interface
            IHHservice HHservice= myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

            //and call it            
            var result = HHservice.PostProperty(r); //input to your method

            ((IClientChannel)HHservice).Close();
            myChannelFactory.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting this error: [System.InvalidOperationException] = {"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference_HomeHunt.IHHservice' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint el...

Comment: This is strange. This error means WCF cant find definition for endpoint in web.config (ABC - address,binding,contract). I except this error with your code. But not with ChannelFactory, becouse I define ABC at the runtime

Comment: 500 (Internal error) have many reasons. Do you have detailed exception? If not try set at service web.config element includeExceptionDetailInFault to true         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> , by default is false, which is good for production but bad for developing. Then you will have detailed exception about error.

Comment: you should check your web.config, maybe re-add the service reference and check if the web.config is configured properly.